# Offset from Last-Row-with-Value in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a simple formula to find the last non-blank row in excel.

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(E:E<>""),E:E)
```

Instead of the last row, I want to find the 7th last row. So I think I want to change this to something like:

```
= OFFSET(LOOKUP(2,1/(E:E<>""),E:E), -7, 0)
```

but I cannot seem to get the syntax working. How can I write a formula to give me the 7th last row?

Comment: `7th last row`?? are you looking for the row 7 rows before or after the last row with data?

Comment: Could there be blanks in the last seven rows? Do you want to skip the blanks? e.g. 2 blank cells would be last row minus 9. Are the values text, numbers or a mix of both?

Comment: I meant the row 7 rows before the last row with data. There aren't any blanks in the data above the last row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For numbers, get the seventh-to-last row number with,

```
=match(1e99, A:A)-7
'get value with,
=index(A:A, match(1e99, A:A)-7)
```

For text, get the seventh-to-last row number with,

```
=match("zzz", A:A)-7
'get value with,
=index(A:A, match("zzz", A:A)-7)
```

For a combination of text and numbers, get the seventh-to-last row number with,

```
=max(iferror(match(1e99, A:A), 8)-7, iferror(match("zzz", A:A), 8)-7, 1)
'get value with,
=index(A:A, max(iferror(match(1e99, A:A), 8)-7, iferror(match("zzz", A:A), 8)-7, 1))
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just find the last row and offset it, regardless of whatever values it holds?

Comment: The [OFFSET function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592) is volatile. Using the [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) to retrieve the row number eliminates the reliance on a volatile function.

Comment: Ah, thanks for letting me know! I was not aware. Good answer!

Comment: hmmm .... depending on how you are defining the 'seventh-to-last' you might need to subtract 6 from the last row, not 7.

Answer (score 0):

This will find you the row that is seven above the last non-blank row using column one. If you want the seventh row below the last blank row, change `-7` to `7`. Of course, make sure you change `"SheetName"` to whatever you worksheet is named (keeping the quotes!).

```
dim seventhLastRow as long

seventhLastRow = Sheets("SheetName").Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(-7, 0).Row
```